# Adbobe after effect: Missing 3D rendering

Tags: adobe

After installing Adobe after effect, it shows "Adobe after effect: Missing 3D rendering". I try to uninstall and reinstall again but it shows the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just after double click on AfterEffect shortcut Hold Ctrl+Alt+Shift. it popup a small window and ask you to delete preferences. ok with that and your software will start working.